# How do I combine positive and negative pulses into one single signal?

Tags: microcontroller, operational-amplifier, signal, automotive

**EDIT:** I kinda solved the problem. I swapped both diodes polarity and then added an op-amp to amplify the resultant signal.

I'm trying to emulate a motorcycle crank pickup signal as shown by **CH2** below (Cyan).

[image: Crank]

I've designed a simple circuit as follows:

[image: Circuit]

- **-12V** negative voltage is generated by **TC1044S**
- **+12V** is supplied by a DC power supply, **3.3V** comes from an LDO
- **CRANK_P_MCU** and **CRANK_N_MCU** are active-low PWM signals generated by an MCU

I've captured **CRANK_P_OUT (CH1, Yellow)** and **CRANK_N_OUT (CH2, Cyan)** signals below. There are no issues with the signals as far I can see.

[image: Separate crank signals]

However, when I combined the signals as below, the negative signal of **CRANK_COMBINED_OUT** signal becomes distorted. And I can clearly hear a buzzing sound coming from the **TC1044S** IC. It works for my application, but I notice that power consumption is greatly increased and the **TC1044S** is warming up.

[image: Crank combined]

[image: Crank combined]

**Questions:**

1. How do I effectively join the signals without distorting the negative crank signal (and probably not killing TC1044S in the long run)?
2. Is there a better solution that I can use to generate the negative crank pulses? For example, would an inverting buffer op-amp work?

Comment: I'm not sure what signal you are trying to produce. Please be clear.

Comment: I am trying to replicate the cyan waveform seen in the first oscilloscope image capture. As you can see, it has both positive and negative portions, akin to a sine wave. However, depending on the speed of the motorcycle, the phase between the positive and negative portions can change. I can create both positive and negative signals separately (2nd & 3rd images), but when I combined them both via diodes (4th image), the signals (5th image) aren't that perfect. So, any ideas on how to effectively combine them?

Comment: If suggest replacing those diodes with capacitors. You only need to AC-couple the pulses through to the output - maybe something around 1uF would work (depending on the impedance of whatever it is you're driving).

Comment: @brhans Thanks, I'll try that.

Comment: A common circuit I’ve seen is to have two of your Q3 configurations with the pickup connected between the two bases of the transistors. You’ll also need a diode from the base to gnd on each transistor and a series resistor to limit the current. The output of one transistor will give you the positive pulse, the other the negative pulse (turned up the right way) so you can just diode or these together.

Comment: For the purposes of emulating this signal to test hardware you can probably run a soft edged square wave from the generator through a series capacitor. But the rising edge will be steep, with a soft downfall.